# Isolate subnets on the same interface

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I need to isolate Subnets on a linux machine CentOS that act as gateway. I have the following scenario.
CentOS

```
eth0 pub ip addres
eth0.1 192.168.1.1
eth0.2 192.168.2.1
```

Now eth0.1 and eth0.2 can communicate but i need to disable this. I can't use VLANs so i need to disable this communication with IPtables. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. You can isolate **only** traffic that passes through your gateway.

For instance you can use that rules:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/24 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j DROP
```

or:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0.1 -o eth0.2 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -o eth0.1 -i eth0.2 -j DROP
```

Both subnets are on the same phisical interface so it looks nice only as long as you have control over all hosts/devices. Otherwise someone can bypass the gateway. There are many ways to do so. For example:

1. change IP to become member of another subnet
2. change IP to any other than one listed above
3. set static, direct route to another subnet
4. use IPv6
5. run DHCP server
   ...

Short answer is that it cannot be done that way.

Comment: What i have now is typical default in the Filter table:
`Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:10050 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination `

Comment: And i was think about to put one deny all rule and then just enable what have to go out. So basically i will just change this rule on Filter table to see what will happen.

Comment: Gateway cannot block traffic that doesn't pass through it.